# What frequency standard does CMHeadphoneMotionManager's startDeviceMotionUpdates() has?

Tags: swift, core-motion, airpods

Same as title. I'm trying to find out what frequency standard does CMHeadphoneMotionManager's startDeviceMotionUpdates() has. Are they only affected by communication environment? or there's something else?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "frequency standard", do you mean sample rate? There is no direct setting for this, but from some experimentation, CoreMotion seems to sample at 25Hz using AirPod Pros v1 using the CMHeadphoneMotionManager.

Answer (score 0):

I also test the sampling frequency, seems like it update the motion data in 25Hz, which is much smaller than the sampling rate of 100Hz on the phone..

Comment: And apple provides the sampling frequency setting in phone, but i didn't find the same API for airpods, i want to have at least 50Hz for my research